# How to determine which version of ios and android supported by particular version of React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I am curious about how to detect which versions of IOS and Android are supported by a particular version of React Native

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You can see required iOS/Android version for the latest release here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native#-requirements (as of now we have React Native 0.71.3 which requires iOS 12.4 and Android 5.0 (API 21))
- Requirement for iOS 12.4 was introduced in 0.70.0: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#0700, was iOS 11 before that
- Requirement for Android API 21 was introduced in 0.64.0: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v0640, was 16 before that

Unfortunately, I couldn't find in which versions the previous requirements (Android API 16, iOS 11) were introduced. It's a shame that RN team didn't make a version compatibility matrix.